# Not able to read file uploaded into Azure Blob

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

while trying to upload document from public url into Blob using startCopy() fails to upload the content of the file

the same url gets uploaded using uploadFromFile(filePath)

non working code

```
URL url =new URL  ("http://irpages2.equitystory.com/download/companies/douglasgmbh/Pres_web/6M_FY2018-19_InvestorUpdate.pdf");

newBlobReference.startCopy(new URI(url.toString()));
```

working code

```
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        try (ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(conn.getInputStream());
                final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {

            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

        }


newBlobReference.uploadFromFile(filePath);
```

would like to upload the documents without having to first download them on local system as this takes time for huge number of document.
Secondly the URL which get downloaded using startCopy() can not be read even when the blob is present in the container

Comment: I don't know Azure but I assume the `URI` provided to `newBlobReference.startCopy` will simply use a `File` instance, if so, you won't be able to use a shortcut like you expect. `File` only access file on a disk (remote disk work) . But it can't manage an `http` URI. So I believe you already have the solution.

Comment: before saving the uri document into blob we provide name to Blob and then copy content to that Blob (via localfilePath/URI). the way this Blob created in either  case would be accessed using the connectionString DefaultEndpointsProtocol=#AccountName=#AccountKey= to get the container then use the blog name to get the blob from the container(blob..openInputStream()). Do you still think there could be a issue in the way i access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with `startCopy` and got the same result as yours, the file doesn't have content. And I don't know the reason so I use the `BlobOutputStream` to upload the file and it worked.The below is my code, you could have a try.

```
        String connectionString = String.format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=%s;AccountKey=%s", ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_KEY);
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobContainer container = null;

        CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();

        container = client.getContainerReference("blobcontainer");

        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("6M_FY2018-19_InvestorUpdate.pdf");

        URL uri =new URL("http://irpages2.equitystory.com/download/companies/douglasgmbh/Pres_web/6M_FY2018-19_InvestorUpdate.pdf");

        InputStream is=uri.openStream();

        BlobOutputStream blobOutputStream = blob.openOutputStream();

        int next = is.read();
        while (next != -1) {
            blobOutputStream.write(next);
            next = is.read();
        }
        blobOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: @Chen, thank you it worked and is saving me step of creating a file and den copying the file to the BLOB. one thing to add though is that the startCopy don't fail for all the URL but few ones , but the once that get saved cant be read from Blob.

Comment: @sushmita, if it helps, please help accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @sushmita, I test with startcopy got the same situation as yours. And what did mean don't fail for all the URL? You mean some url could store the right blob,right?

Comment: @Chen , yes some save the bob , but reading the is still a problem